# How can I replace PrimeFaces DataTable pagination with custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

I want to replace the standard DataTable pagination buttons with a custom JSF h:outputtext.

This is the current impl:

[image]

Now I need to change the button completely. The problem is that I'm using JSF messages.properties file because of different languages.

This is how it should looks like:

[image]

So I first thought that I can replace it with JS but this can't work because of different languages. So when a user is a chinese person, the text must change from "Next" to "下一個" and this can't be done via a JS script because the DOM is already loaded and JS has no JSF functionality.

This is the next button from the DOM:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-paginator-next ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" aria-label="Next Page" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next">N</span></a>
```

So I need to do something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-paginator-next ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" aria-label="Next Page" tabindex="0"><span>#{msgs.nextMessage} &rarr;</span></a>
```

But how?

Comment: `can't be done via a JS script because the DOM is already loaded and JS has no JSF functionality` You're wrong here. JSF is a server side framework, which sends to the browser just HTML, CSS and JS code. Once the DOM gets built in the browser, you can do whatever you want with Javascript to manipulate it (I mean, as long as you don't alter any original id or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You should have multiple messages.properties files, each for your different language right? An example below showing how I'd make an app that deals with English and Spainish.

You'll have a message.properties with: `greeting = Hello!`

You'll then want a message_sp.properties with: `greeting = Hola!`

You will need to update you faces-config.xml you'll have want to make sure you have following.

```
 <application>
     <locale-config>
         <default-locale>en_GB</default-locale>
         <supported-locale>sp</supported-locale>
     </locale-config>

     <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>uk.police.ecis.message</base-name>
         <var>message</var>
     </resource-bundle>
 </application>
```

Then in your JSF file, write something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="paginatorStyle" aria-label="Next Page" tabindex="0"><span>#{message.greeting} &rarr;</span></a>
```

It'll figure out the rest for you. Internationalization within JSF is what you are trying to do. Hope that helps.

Comment: Not possible because I can't edit a generated component HTML tag this way.